# $pV=nRT $: Is this rudimentary proof correct in its assumptions?

Tags: ideal-gas

> I had a quick check in the help page (there wasn't much info on these
> types of questions). It looks to be allowed

I know this doesn't technically constitute as proof (since it assumes other equations are correct though I minimised this as far as possible). I just wanted a logical reasoning for the ideal gas equation:

$pV=nRT$

Hence:

$\frac{V}{n}∝\frac{T}{P}$

$\frac{V}{n}$= The volume of a single nucleus (since we assume that's where all mass is centred)

$\frac{V}{n}∝{M_r∝{m}}$ Since molecular density is constant

$m∝\frac{1}{2}{m}{v^2}∝{T}$ Since temperature is just equally distributed kinetic energy

Therefore:

$\frac{V}{n}∝{T}$

Resolving for $P$:

Since pressure is just total force within a fixed volume. For each additional particle it increases linearly (assuming elastic pressure). Hence:

${n}∝{P}$

$\frac{1}{n}∝\frac{1}{P}$

The two results combined result in the ideal gas law.

**The question: How accurate is the logic applied to reach the gas equation (I'm not too fussed about how much it qualifies as proof)?**

Comment: first V/n =volume of a single nucleus is wrong, 2. pressure is just total force within a fixed volume is wrong, 3. m proportional to m is wrong. so your arguments do not hold

Comment: In addition to the mistakes, you started assuming what you wanted to prove, so it is not a proof, it is circular logic

Comment: @Trula sounds like an answer. Though I never used the acc equation in my answer, just the expressions on either side; not sure if that constitutes as circular logic.

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean gramatically speaking; if you mean do I know what they stand for then yes...

Comment: You've used the ideal gas law to prove the ideal gas law... you've completed the circle of life

Comment: So I would still be using the ideal gas law if I scrubbed off the first two equations and slapped them at the end?

Comment: @trula again; it sounds like an answer to me.

Comment: I deleted my comment since i could not edit it any more. I told you that your argument is very wrong, but not circular. I was asking for a definition of n since it seams you think of n as the number of atoms or molecules?

Comment: Yh no I was taught it was the moles of the substance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The question: How accurate is the logic applied to reach the gas
> equation (I'm not too fussed about how much it qualifies as proof)?

Not very. It seems to me you somehow, by mathematical manipulation, arrived at the ideal gas equation using the following incorrect statements.

> $\frac{V}{n}$= The volume of a single nucleus (since we assume that's
> where all mass is centered)

$V$ is not the volume of a single nucleus. $n$ is the number of moles of gas. So $\frac{V}{n}$ is volume per mole of gas. One mole of gas equals the mass of the gas divided by the molecular weight of the gas. Therefore, for example, one gram-mole of oxygen gas equals 32 grams of oxygen (molecular weight of oxygen gas being 32).

> $\frac{V}{n}∝{M_r∝{m}}$ Since molecular density is constant

I'm not sure I even follow this. What is $M_r$? Is $m$ mass? What is meant by $\frac{V}{n}α$ $m$? The last relationship is, for a given molecular weight gas, equivalent to saying that volume divided by mass equals mass (????).

> $m∝\frac{1}{2}{m}{v^2}∝{T}$ Since temperature is just equally
> distributed kinetic energy

Mass is proportional to mass? What is the purpose of that? At least yes, temperature is proportional to kinetic energy (more accurately average kinetic energy). This is perhaps the one argument that makes sense since kinetic energy is not explicitly shown in the ideal gas equation, and the ideal gas equation is derived from the kinetic theory of gases.

> Since pressure is just total force within a fixed volume.

No it isn't. For a fixed volume pressure is the force per unit area exerted on the walls of the container of gas.

Hope this  helps.

Comment: Hmm... I think that somme of my phrasing has led to a misconception, but that doesn't illegitimise your answer. You're right on V/n; somehow I got it in my head that n was a co-effocient of avagadros constant (which when meaauring total number of particles is the case but that's not n). Hence my logic thereafter is flawed (for future reference Mr is Relative Molecular Mass). Essensitially my logic was that since the volume of a nucleus was filled completely with mass, it's KE would increase linearly with V/n (assuming my error) which would increase linearly with temperature.

Comment: As for pressure. Yh no I get it's official definition. I was just trying (and failing) to put it inot wprds which would express how multiple forces (quantified by n) of equal magnitude acting within a fixed surface area (volume) would create linearity between the resultant pressure and n

Comment: But thanks for the answer.

Comment: @yolo You're right that V/n got you off track. But it happens to all of us (though some may not want to admit it!).